# Reduce iterating over a zip list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, functools

Consider the following code, which uses `functools.reduce` to concatenate a list of dataframes:

```
from functools import reduce
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [3, 4]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [5, 6]})

reduce(lambda x, y: pd.concat([x, y], axis=1), [df1, df2, df3])
```

This code works well. However, when I try the following, I get errors:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: pd.concat([x[0], y[0]], axis=1), zip([df1, df2, df3], [0, 1, 0]))
```

Could someone please help me to understand that?

Comment: What are the errors you receive? Also, is this for a mere exercise since `pandas.concat` does not require `reduce` as used here? Finally, your issue may be the need to use `zip`. What is the use case for `zip`? I feel this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you are asking about your _y_ solution to use `reduce` + `zip` and not about your actual _x_ problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Parfait, for tour comment! I am coming to Python from R. In R, `reduce` can have more arguments than in Python [`purrr::reduce2`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/reduce), and I was trying to add more arguments to `reduce` by using `zip`. That is why my posted question emerged!

Comment: The closer counterpart of Python's standard library `reduce` would be base R's `Reduce`. These are known high-order functional methods in most programming languages (Map, Reduce, Filter) (i.e., Python's `map` to R's `Map`/`mapply` and Python's `filter` to R's `Filter`). I find tidyverse methods usually extends base methods and may not translate 1-to-1 to other languages.

Comment: Thanks, @Parfait, for your comment! By understanding now the way Python `reduce` internally works, thanks to the Shubham Sharma's explanation, I was able to circumvent the reported errors by using the following code: `reduce(lambda x, y: pd.concat([x if isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame) else x[0], y[0]], axis=1), zip([df1, df2, df3], [0, 1, 0]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's understand what's going on in `reduce`:

```
# Iteration 1: 
# x = (df1, 0); y = (df2, 1)
# reduce(x, y): pd.concat([x[0], y[0]], axis=1) # okay
# Now the result of `reduce(x, y)` is a dataframe which will be used as new x for iteration 2

# Iteration 2: 
# x = some_dataframe, y = (df3, 0)
# reduce(x, y): pd.concat([x[0], y[0]], axis=1) # error
# Notice that x is not a tuple anymore but a dataframe instead.
# So calling dataframe[0] will raise an key error because there is no such column in the dataframe
```

In case you are interested in a implementation of `reduce`, here is the  minimal implementation:

```
def reduce(func, sequence):
    if not sequence:
        raise TypeError('Empty sequence')

    result = sequence[0]
    for item in sequence[1:]:
        result = func(result, item)
    
    return result
```